# SpringBoot deployment on ubuntu

Tags: hibernate, deployment, spring-boot, tomcat8

I deploied my first springboot web application on tomcat (ubuntu14.04), but the result is: i can not start the application.

some information about the web appliation:
springboot1.33 + springMVC + mysql + hibernate.

some information about the server:
ubuntu14.04 + apache-tomcat-8.33 + jdk1.8.0_91

And I found the fact that if i not not use module about mysql, hibernate, i can deploy the application successfully. In the mean time, I can not see any errors or logs on the server.

What should I do to solve this problem? Waiting online!

Comment: Check that your database is created, that is the same you're using for your tests and that you've got access to it with same credentials.

Comment: i do the same thing in window7 and it works, i want to know why it doesn't work on ubuntu. (the version of jdk and tomcat is the same for both platforms)